# The divs won't sit side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am having some difficulty getting my div elements to sit side by side with each other. There is sufficient width on the page for one div to sit next to the other, but it just seems to sit beneath the other div.

HTML parent component:

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="header">
    <div>
      <h1>Information & Advice</h1>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <h2>From The Daylight Experts</h2>
    </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <app-carousel></app-carousel>
    <app-instagram></app-instagram> 
    <app-guides></app-guides>
  </div>     
</div>
```

CSS parent:

```
.Container {
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}
```

app-carousel component.html:

```
<div class="carouselContainer">
  <mdb-carousel class="carousel slide carousel-fade" [animation]="'fade'">
    <mdb-carousel-item>
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
    </mdb-carousel-item>
    <mdb-carousel-item>
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </mdb-carousel-item>
    <mdb-carousel-item>
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </mdb-carousel-item>
  </mdb-carousel>
</div>
```

app-carousel component.css:

```
.carouselContainer {
  width: 59.5%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

app-instagram component .html:

```
<div class="instagramContainer">
  <div id="curator-feed-default-layout">
    <a href="https://curator.io" target="_blank" class="crt-logo crt-tag">Powered by Curator.io</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

app-instagram component .css:

```
.instagramContainer {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

This currently makes the instagram `<div>` sit under the carousel `<div>`. I want them side by side, which I thought could be achieved by just floating the child elements of the container.

Comment: use `flex-direction:row` in the parent property, it will move another div to the row.

Comment: Time to forget about good old CSS 2.0 `float` and its headaches, and use something modern and robust like [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: stop using absolute positioning for a start. also remember to remove browser-added padding at the top of your css file using the asterisk 'all' selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it clean using `flex` that will give your clear visibility, this may help you to get going with your changes.

```css
.Container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  /* you need this to move content side by side */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* provide the width for parent */
  width: 800px;
}

.header {
  /* inherit parent width */
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  /* inherit parent width */
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="header">
    <div>
      <h1>Information & Advice</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>From The Daylight Experts</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">Your wrapper content here...
    <app-carousel></app-carousel>
    <app-instagram></app-instagram>
    <app-guides></app-guides>
  </div>
</div>
```